# Repeating a state in a state machine

Tags: design, design-patterns, architecture, finite-state-machine

I have a state machine in which I might have to **restart** something when needed (Say restart a hardware). But after restarting, I need to run some tests on the thing. If the tests fail, I need to stop the thing and exit the state machine with a failure status.

In case of failure, how should I handle the 2nd stopping of the thing? The state machine diagram loses its readability if I do it the following way. And the implementation becomes ugly since I need to decide `Stop thing` state's output based on the previous state (`SUCCESS` the first time and `ERROR` if the state was reached after failing the tests)

[image: Option1]

My other option is to create a 2nd instance of the `Stop thing` state as follows. But then it makes the state machine bigger

[image: Option2]

Which one of these is the correct approach? Or is there another way to approach these kind of problems?

If it matters here, I am using `ROS` and `smach` for the state machine implementation

Comment: Please state the reason for the downvote

Comment: I didn't vote yet, but see this: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/839601)

Comment: I can understand a downvote if my question was asking to check/ rewrite a code. But this is a real architectural problem I have faced for which I could not find anyone who was able to give me a clear answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first statemachine does not accurately reflect the desired behaviour you described. In the first statemachine, you keep retrying to restart the "thing" until either the tests pass or stopping fails.

Your second statemachine *does* show the desired behaviour of trying to restart the "thing" once and stopping it again when the tests fail.

Note that a state is not defined by the actions that are performed in the state, but more by the transitions leading out of the state. This also means that a state should not need to know how it was reached. If the path leading up to a state is relevant for how the state reacts to events, then it is really multiple states. As the transitions for `Stop thing 1` and `Stop thing 2` are completely different, it is entirely correct to model them as two different states, even if they take the same actions and respond (albeit differently) to the same events.

Comment: Sorry yeah that was misleading. Edited the question on the first state machine.  `Stop thing` state will exit with `SUCCESS` if it is the first time and `ERROR` if the state was reached after failing the tests in the fist state machine

Comment: @TeshanShanukaJ, a state should not need to know how it was reached. If the path leading up to a state is relevant for how the state reacts to events, then it is really multiple states.

Comment: Bart, say it in the answer.